# Is getDefaultAdapter() still valid on Android 4.3+?

Tags: android, bluetooth

From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.htm) it is said that:

> To get a BluetoothAdapter representing the local Bluetooth adapter, when running on `JELLY_BEAN_MR1` and below, call the static `getDefaultAdapter()` method; when running on `JELLY_BEAN_MR2` and higher, retrieve it through `getSystemService(String)` with `BLUETOOTH_SERVICE`.

I believe this change is due to the added support for **Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)**, but does that mean that the old way of using `getDefaultAdapter()` method of the `BluetoothAdapter` class is deprecated? If so this is not stated explicitly.

The reason I'm asking is that I do not need support for BLE and I have an existing Java class implemented the bluetooth functionality in the pre-4.3 way. Will this work on 4.3 and 4.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now tested the pre-JELLY_BEAN_MR2 on Android 4.4.2 and it works.